# Playing video file in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, wmv

I want to play the video file and it's like

```
http://test.XXXX.com/myfile.wmv
```

am using `Video view` for that but it saying `unable to play video error`

I tried using `WebView` also but it showing only blank page.

Just i want to `play that video link file in device online`.

How to do that ?

**Note** : The links are working i tested on Windows browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to transcode the video to an android supported format and make the result available on your server as well.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html provides an official overview of supported forms, but you may have more practical look googling for instructions on transcoding for android devices.

Comment: That's what web searches are for.  For one thing, you'll need to decide if you want a convenient (gui?) tool for doing it manually while maintaining your site, or if you want a scriptable tool to run on a web site that sees a lot of (user generated?) content turn over.